# Elementary OS does not shutdown completely

Tags: release-hera

When I press the shutdown button, it is as if it turned off, no lights or anything come on, but when I press a key even if it is off, the PC turns on again.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly set the power button in power management. And instead of poweroff it hibernates the machine. Change it please.